# Google Text-To-Speech API always translates text with FEMALE voice

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

We are using

```
googlecloud.tts
```

library for translating our text to speech. For some reason, Google now translates all requests to SsmlGender.FEMALE voice, even on SsmlGender.MALE requests.

Is this known issue or should we try something?
(Problem came out of nowhere, no changes were done to the code for couple of years)

For local tests, we can be sure that it is working correct with the same API key as we have in production.

Comment: @Solar Mike, we are using a Basic support offering, so we don't have the ability to ask Google tech support questions like this

Comment: did you find any solution? I get exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below alternative:

By using [Text-to-Speech Custom Voice](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/custom-voice/docs), this can translate request for both
`SsmlGender.FEMALE` and `SsmlGender.MALE`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you actually have to specify a voice name, as this seems to work now:

```
        string googleVoiceName;

        if (languageCode == "zh-TW")
        {
            if (VoiceName == "Google Male")
                googleVoiceName = "cmn-TW-Standard-B";
            else
                googleVoiceName = "cmn-TW-Standard-A";
        }
        else
            googleVoiceName = "";

        // You can specify a particular voice, or ask the server to pick based
        // on specified criteria.
        VoiceSelectionParams voiceSelection = new VoiceSelectionParams
        {
            LanguageCode = languageCode,
            SsmlGender = (VoiceName == "Google Female"
                ? SsmlVoiceGender.Female
                : SsmlVoiceGender.Male),
            Name = googleVoiceName  // New line
        };
```

But it used to work. Maybe instead of a voice name, adding other criteria?